# How to configure Oracle HTTP server apache mod_proxy to proxy certain HTTPS requests to external (origin) server over HTTPS

Tags: oracle, apache, proxy, mod-proxy, oracle-application-server

I got two different application running on Two different servers
    1. **server1** **app1** is lets say **"abc.com"** and I am making api post request **"https abc.com/api/v1/clientId/setdata"**. This server resides on company's virtual private cloud. Its based on Oracle application server that uses OHS. 
    2.There is one more application running on external server **server2** **app2** lets say **"xyz.com"**. This server is running on Amazon AWS with apache web server.

Now my question is : for certain clientIds I want to proxy request from abc.com to xyz.com as  **"https xyz.com/api/clientId/setdata"**

Steps I performed.

I modified the apache rewrite rule at server 1 "abc.com" as below

```
RewriteRule ^/api/v1/testClient/(.*) https://xyz.com/api/testClient/setdata [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse  / https://xyz.com/
```

But I am getting below error when I send api request "https://abc.com/api/v1/testClient/445

```
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /api/certs/v1/testClient/445.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

Can anybody please explain what this error is abut . I do not see anything in access logs of xyz.com. 
How the request flow goes when somebody tries to proxy https request to external server ?

What is best solution to above problem ?